# Java: GridLayout add to specific cell

Tags: java, layout, grid-layout

how to add data to specific cell for example ([*] indicates a cell):
[JButton1]
[JButton2]
[]
[]
[JButton3]

Or is there any better solution rather than using null layout to get similar result - giving a gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridLayout of JPanels each with a CardLayout.  When you want something to appear in a particular x,y position, add it to the JPanel and show that card.